# Flask square brackets and single quotas at showing all validation message at once

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms

I have created a very simple login form with flask

```
    email = StringField('E-Mail:',  validators=[validators.DataRequired(message='E-mail needed.'), validators.email(u'Provide e-mail.')])
    password = StringField('Password:', [validators.required(u'Password can't be empty.')])
```

And the macro which will create the form inside the template:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ field(**kwargs) | safe }}
    </div>
</fieldset>
{% endmacro %}
```

As you can see it is very simple form. In the flask tutorial it was showing validation erors for individual fields. But I just want to show them all at once on the top of the form.

Here is my template for that:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    {% if loginForm.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            {% for error in loginForm.errors %}
                                <li>{{ loginForm.errors[error] }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
                        {% from "_formhelper.html" import render_field %}
                        <fieldset>
                            {{ render_field(loginForm.email, class="form-control", placeholder="E-Mail") }}
                            {{ render_field(loginForm.password, class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
                            <button  class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

As you can see, i placed my error section on the top of the form. But when
I post empty form, it shows the error messages like this:

['Password can't be empty'] instead of Password can't be empty

Why does it append square brackets and single quotas, start and end of the message? I don't know.

Comment: It's because in more complicated forms there can be more than one error. loginForm.errors[error] returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but if anyone else has this problem you can fix it by adding a for loop for the messages, something like this:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning my-5">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```